# How to use custom field in the HTML of Magento 2 pagebuilder?

Tags: magento2, page-builder

I added a custom field to all pagebuilder blocks, this was fairly easy to do with a single file in my custom module.

`<MyVendor>/PagebuilderExtend/view/adminhtml/ui_component/pagebuilder_base_form.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="advanced">
        <field name="anchor" sortOrder="70" formElement="input">
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Anchor</label>
                <notice translate="true">Anchor name for internal linking so it can be referenced on another place in the html.</notice>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

This makes sure the "anchor" field is added as an input field to every pagebuilder content type.

[image]

**Question:** how can I use this data in the HTML output of pagebuilder?

Example:

Anchor: `my-anchor`

Current pagebuilder output: `<div></div>`

What I want: `<div id="my-anchor" ... ></div>`

How can I achieve this **for all content types**?

This will be used for internal linking from the same page for large content pages. (Go to My Anchor)

Comment: Hi Akif , can you please let me know that in the HTML content only 1 div tag will be present is that right ?

Comment: @BharathKumarJ that is right.

Answer (score 6):

> **Try This Code**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName**

**registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'VendoreName_ModuleName',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc**

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendoreName_ModuleName">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component**

**pagebuilder_base_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="advanced">
        <field name="anchor" sortOrder="70" formElement="input">
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Anchor</label>
                <notice translate="true">Anchor name for internal linking so it can be referenced on another place in the html.</notice>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/pagebuilder/content_type**

**block.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_PageBuilder:etc/content_type.xsd">
    <type name="block">
        <appearances>
            <appearance name="default">
                <elements>
                    <element name="main">
                        <attribute name="anchor" source="data-anchor"/>
                    </element>
                </elements>
            </appearance>
        </appearances>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="DefaultWYSIWYGValidator">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="allowedAttributes" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="data-anchor" xsi:type="string">data-anchor</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

*Here I put code only for block.xml, you need to add and override every content type which you want to show **anchor** in HTML. I put one reference module to show how to override another content type.*

[Click here to download the reference module.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jsMHBrHJclurFtx9aqI2peWm39wkXo2G)

[Click here to show Demo Videos](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-Hr9Irukw2clyof-yR7pu28gfBH7xSI1/view)

**Must Run Magento Commands after adding new content type**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

Comment: Hi @Msquare the anchor field is showing on all content types of page builder but if we save some value in that anchor text field that is not saving.. How can we save the value..I tried the below ''custom-data-attributes.js" and "custom-data-attribute-provider.js" with as it is content in specified folders but still the value is not saving. Can you put those files as well to complete this module ?

Comment: @shankarboss you can get the module link above which is working fine. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jsMHBrHJclurFtx9aqI2peWm39wkXo2G

Comment: I am sorry I installed that google drive module only but the anchor text field value is not saving in database. after that I put the below mentioned js files in that module but still not saving the value. You mean the drive module is enough for everything without using any js files ? So that I will try to install it again. I don't see any js files in the give google drive module. is that not necessery or google drive did not allow to upload js files ? If possible can you share the complete working module please

Comment: Yes, you just installed the module and checked it. I verified it before posting it here.

Comment: Hi @Msquare once again :). yes everything working as expected. the data-attribute is displaying correctly in CMS i.e. home page but in category listing page we are displaying some images between products but for those images this data-attribute (data-anchor) is not showing. how can we add this data-attribute for all pages where ever banner/image displayed ?

Comment: @shankarboss Can you please post a new question so that we can better understand your requirements and provide you with the best solution?

Comment: done..!! please check this : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/371009/added-custom-field-attribute-to-magento-2-pagebuilder-all-content-types-but-the

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by editing the content type definition xml of each content type. You will have to add the following attribute to the appearance(s):

```
<attribute name="anchor" source="id"/>
```

As example for the text content type:
*Vendor/PagebuilderExtend/view/adminhtml/pagebuilder/content_type/text.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_PageBuilder:etc/content_type.xsd">
    <type name="text">
        <appearances>
            <appearance name="default">
                <elements>
                    <element name="main">
                        <attribute name="anchor" source="id"/>
                    </element>
                </elements>
            </appearance>
        </appearances>
    </type>
</config>
```

And additionally you need to allow the id attribute in the WYSIWYG validation, otherwise it will be filtered. You can allow more attributes by extending the `DefaultWYSIWYGValidator` virtual type in a *di.xml*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="DefaultWYSIWYGValidator" type="Magento\Framework\Validator\HTML\ConfigurableWYSIWYGValidator">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="allowedAttributes" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="id" xsi:type="string">id</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

Then it will be automatically applied as attribute. `name` maps to the form field and `source` maps to the attribute name in the html.

This works with every content type that as `attr="data.main.attributes"` in its master template (I think it should be all of them but I did not check every template).

Comment: Thanks, this works for the text content type. But I was fiddling with `block.xml`, and it does not work for it. Any ideas why? The anchor field is visible, but when I save it and reload the admin page, the field is empty (not saved). Did I accidentally pick the wrong one to test with? Since I must have tried this solution already. It has `data.main.attributes` in the html btw.

Comment: The field is empty due to id being filtered in validation. I added the step to allow the id attribute within the pagebuilder.

Answer (score 0):

For the custom field to save the data, you will have to create custom-data-attribute js to save the object value at the backend.

In Your module: /PagebuilderExtend/view/adminhtml/ui_component/pagebuilder_base_form.xml
create file:
/PagebuilderExtend/view/adminhtml/web/js/converter/attribute/custom-data-attributes.js

```
define([
'underscore',
'Magento_PageBuilder/js/utils/object'
], function (_underscore, _object) {
     let CustomDataAttributes = /*#__PURE__*/ function () {
    'use strict';

    function CustomDataAttributes() {}

    let _proto = CustomDataAttributes.prototype;

    /**
     * Convert value to internal format.
     *
     * @param value string
     * @returns {string | object}
     */
    _proto.fromDom = function fromDom(value) {
        if (value && value !== '') {
            return JSON.parse(value);
        }

        return;
    };

    /**
     * Convert value to knockout format.
     *
     * @param name string
     * @param data Object
     * @returns {string | object}
     */
    _proto.toDom = function toDom(name, data) {
        let content = (0, _object.get)(data, name);

        if (_underscore.isString(content) && content !== '') {
            content = JSON.parse(content);
        }

        if (content && Object.keys(content).length) {
            return JSON.stringify(content);
        }

        return;
    };

    return CustomDataAttributes;
}();

return CustomDataAttributes;
```

});

// also create the event file to save data after:
*Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/js/form/custom-data-attribute-provider.js*

```
define([
'Magento_Ui/js/form/provider',
'Magento_PageBuilder/js/events'
], function (Provider, events) {
 'use strict';

return Provider.extend({
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    initClient: function () {
        return this;
    },

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    save: function () {
        events.trigger('customDataAttributes:saveAfter', this.get('data'));

        return this;
    }
});
```

});

For reference please this link: https://github.com/pykettk/module-page-builder-custom-data-attributes