# Added custom field/attribute to magento 2 pageBuilder all content types but the attribute is not displaying on frontend html

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, frontend, category-listing, page-builder

I extended magento 2 pageBuilder media content types (image, banner, slide, slider etc..). So if I add any value in that custom field that will be displaying on frontend CMS (home) page correctly but I have the image/banner in category listing page as well at some of the positions. If I add any value to my custom pageBuilder field the value is not showing in frontend category listing page html.can you guide me how can we display/show the custom field in all pages where ever I add some value to my custom field.
Ref : [How to use custom field in the HTML of Magento 2 pagebuilder?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/359827/how-to-use-custom-field-in-the-html-of-magento-2-pagebuilder/360590?noredirect=1#comment508723_360590)